# Почему не работает код JS когда запускаешь сайт

Tags: javascript

Код не выполняется и пишется вот такая ошибка "Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'btns' has already been declared"

```js
let btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn_');

for (let i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {    
        document.querySelectorAll('.items').forEach(function(el) {
            el.style.display = 'none';
        }); 
        
        document.querySelector(`.${this.dataset.menuName}`).style.display = 'block';
    });
}
```

```css
html {
    background: yellow;
}

.d-none {
  display: none;
}

.menu {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 370px;
    background: red;
}

.basket {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 370px;
    background: red;
}

.block_mini {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 85px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background: black;
}

.btn {
    display: flex;
}

.btn_ {
    background: white;
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.block_mini_1 {
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 85px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>  
    <div class="items menu"> <!-- по нажатию на кнопку "меню" -->
      <div class="block_mini"></div>
      <div class="block_mini"></div>
      <div class="block_mini"></div>
      <div class="block_mini"></div>
      <div class="block_mini"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="items basket d-none"> 
      <div class="block_mini_1"></div>
      <div class="block_mini_1"></div>
      <div class="block_mini_1"></div>
      <div class="block_mini_1"></div>
      <div class="block_mini_1"></div>
    </div>  

  <div class="btn">
    <button class="btn_" data-menu-name="menu">меню</button>
    <button class="btn_" data-menu-name="basket">корзина</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ну, тут всё работает нормально -_-

Comment: Я когда в бразуере запускаю страницу сайта с JS кодом он выдает ошибку "Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'btns' has already been declared"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

переместите main.js  в конец страницы. У вас срабатывает скрипт до рендеринга DOM.

```js
let btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn_');

for (let i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {    
        document.querySelectorAll('.items').forEach(function(el) {
            el.style.display = 'none';
        }); 
        
        document.querySelector(`.${this.dataset.menuName}`).style.display = 'block';
    });
}
```

```css
html {
    background: yellow;
}

.d-none {
  display: none;
}

.menu {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 370px;
    background: red;
}

.basket {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 370px;
    background: red;
}

.block_mini {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 85px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background: black;
}

.btn {
    display: flex;
}

.btn_ {
    background: white;
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.block_mini_1 {
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 85px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>  
    <div class="items menu"> <!-- по нажатию на кнопку "меню" -->
      <div class="block_mini"></div>
      <div class="block_mini"></div>
      <div class="block_mini"></div>
      <div class="block_mini"></div>
      <div class="block_mini"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="items basket d-none"> 
      <div class="block_mini_1"></div>
      <div class="block_mini_1"></div>
      <div class="block_mini_1"></div>
      <div class="block_mini_1"></div>
      <div class="block_mini_1"></div>
    </div>  

  <div class="btn">
    <button class="btn_" data-menu-name="menu">меню</button>
    <button class="btn_" data-menu-name="basket">корзина</button>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Comment: А JQuery тоже ставить в конце?

Comment: @RuslanMelikov Зависит от задач. Но в целом можно всё и в начало. только вот нужно следить за тем что и как запускается

Answer (score 2):

Судя по тексту ошибки `Identifier 'btns' has already been declared` у Вас в какой-то другой части js-кода уже объявлена переменная `btns`.